# Codesign signs my framework as a directory. Why?

Tags: ios, code-signing

I have troubles with the code signing. 
I am trying to codesign a framework and use the following command in my script

```
codesign --verbose --force --sign $(EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY) $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${app}>/Frameworks/${fw}.framework
```

Fo some reasons, that I can't understand, I have my framework signed as a directory

[image]

When I do `codesign -vvv  myLibrary.framework`, everything is reported as properly signed, but later when I try to load the framework with dlopen, I see the error that signature is incorrect.

Why do I have it signed as directory ?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Info.plist should specify executable and it was not set correctly. It was set to the directory name basically.
So, signcode signs everything as directory.